# Infura V3 spec cannot find Project Id

Tags: infura

I used to use the old version of infura and it worked just fine. The latest version is not working as it states that it cannot find the id despite it being there.

https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/da3717f25f824cc1baa32d812386d93f

Error log:

```
Error=-25300, query={
   class = inet;
   “m_Limit” = “m_LimitAll”;
   ptcl = htps;
   “r_Attributes” = 1;
   sdmn = “Project ID is required in the URL”;
   srvr = “mainnet.infura.io”;
   sync = syna;
}
```

Snippet: https://github.com/AlphaWallet/alpha-wallet-ios/blob/master/AlphaWallet/Tokens/Helpers/CallSmartContractFunction.swift